# Shiny app to bind data only saves one name

Tags: shiny, rbind

I am trying to build a shiny app to learn how it works. I have run into a problem. I am building an input form to track input data; specifically golfers in this case. The shiny apps run but don't save more than 1 input. For example, it demos Player 1 and Players 2 as they are coded in under the server. When I dynamically add Player 3 - it works. But when I add Player 4 it overwrites players 3.

Thank you for your help. I have read about 100 pages and can't seem to find a simple answer.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

############################################# GOLF SHINY APP ####################################################

#building the shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("sandstone"),
  #user driven inputs for new golfers
  titlePanel("Stableford App"),
  navbarPage("App Options",
             tabPanel("New Golfer", 
                      br(),
                      br(),
                      textInput("name", "Initial Golfer's name", value = "Add Name Here"),
                      numericInput("hd_cap", "Whats the Golfer's Handicap?", value = 15, min = 0, max = 50),
                      sliderInput("goal_score", "Initial Stableford Goal?", value = 10, min = 0, max = 60),
                      actionButton("add_golfer", ("Add Golfer!"), icon = icon("cocktail"), class="btn btn-danger btn-block")),
             
             tabPanel("View Golfers",
                      actionButton("gen_golfers", "Update Golfer List"),
                      dataTableOutput("initial_golfer_list"),
                      dataTableOutput("golfer_list")
  )

)
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  #building the rbind information for players
  name <- c('Player 1', 'Player 2')
  hd_cap <- c(2,10)
  sgoal <- c(40,22)
  big_golfer_list <- data.frame(name, hd_cap, sgoal) 
  big_golfer_list <- setNames(big_golfer_list, c("Golfer", "Handicap", "Target"))
  
  PlayerData <-  eventReactive(input$gen_golfers,{
    big_golfer_list <- rbind(big_golfer_list,
                              data.frame("Golfer" = input$name, "Handicap" = input$hd_cap, "Target" = input$goal_score))
  })

  #table with all names
  output$golfer_list = renderDataTable(
    FinalData <- PlayerData() %>% filter(Golfer != "Add Name Here"))

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retain the previous values you need to use `<<-`.  Otherwise, it just adds one golfer name to your existing two names in the list. See the change below to get your desired behavior.

**Update:** I have modified your code a bit to use only the first action button.  Also, the selections are in the sidebar now. A reset button allows you to start over, and you can modify any entry in your display table.

```
############# GOLF SHINY APP ##############

#building the shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("sandstone"),
  #user driven inputs for new golfers
  titlePanel("Stableford App"),
  navbarPage("App Options",
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                  br(),
                  textInput("name", "Initial Golfer's name", value = "Add Name Here"),
                  numericInput("hd_cap", "Whats the Golfer's Handicap?", value = 15, min = 0, max = 50),
                  sliderInput("goal_score", "Initial Stableford Goal?", value = 10, min = 0, max = 60),
                  actionButton("add_golfer", ("Add Golfer!"), icon = icon("cocktail"), class="btn btn-danger btn-block"),
                  actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Reset", class="btn btn-primary")

                ),
                mainPanel(
                  tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel("New Golfer",
                             br(),
                             br(),
                             # textInput("name", "Initial Golfer's name", value = "Add Name Here"),
                             # numericInput("hd_cap", "Whats the Golfer's Handicap?", value = 15, min = 0, max = 50),
                             # sliderInput("goal_score", "Initial Stableford Goal?", value = 10, min = 0, max = 60),
                             # actionButton("add_golfer", ("Add Golfer!"), icon = icon("cocktail"), class="btn btn-danger btn-block"),
                             DTOutput("golfersnames")
                    ),

                    tabPanel("View Golfers",
                             # actionButton("gen_golfers", "Update Golfer List"),
                             # dataTableOutput("initial_golfer_list"),
                             dataTableOutput("golfer_list")
                    )
                  )

                )

             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  #building the rbind information for players
  name <- c('Player 1', 'Player 2')
  hd_cap <- c(2,10)
  sgoal <- c(40,22)
  big_golfer_list <- data.frame(name, hd_cap, sgoal)
  big_golfer_list <- setNames(big_golfer_list, c("Golfer", "Handicap", "Target"))

  DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=big_golfer_list)
  orig_d1 <- big_golfer_list

  PlayerData <-  eventReactive(input$add_golfer,{
    big_golfer_list <<- rbind(big_golfer_list,
                             data.frame("Golfer" = input$name, "Handicap" = input$hd_cap, "Target" = input$goal_score))
  })

  observeEvent(input$add_golfer, {
    DF1$data <- PlayerData()
    output$golfersnames <- renderDT(DF1$data, editable = TRUE)
  })

  #table with all names
  output$golfer_list = renderDataTable(
    FinalData <- PlayerData() %>% filter(Golfer != "Add Name Here"))

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    DF1$data <- orig_d1
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: YBS - that works to add the extra individuals. However, I cannot add multiple golfers via the "Add Golfer!" action button in a row. You have to hit the "Update Golfer List" button in between each golfer. Is there a reason for this? Is there a way to update multiple golfers to the DF big_golfer_list without rebuilding the table? Also, every time you click the "Update Golfer List" button it adds the last golfers name again. Thoughts?